# Create a local branch to track a remote branch with libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

How can I create a local branch that tracks a remote branch with libgit2sharp? The git equivalent would be:

```
git branch --track development origin/development
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code should just do that, assuming the local `development` branch doesn't exist yet.

```
const string testBranchName = "development";
const string trackedBranchName = "origin/development";

using (var repo = new Repository(path))
{
    // Retrieve remote tracking branch
    Branch trackedBranch = repo.Branches[trackedBranchName];
    Debug.Assert(trackedBranch.IsRemote == true);

    // Create local branch pointing at the same Commit
    Branch branch = repo.CreateBranch(testBranchName, trackedBranch.Tip);

    repo.Branches.Update(branch,
        b => b.TrackedBranch = trackedBranch.CanonicalName);
}
```

**Note:** The **[BranchFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/a4c6c4552b24590995c221304e7d7c75c181ea82/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/BranchFixture.cs#L574-L603)** suite contains a `CanSetTrackedBranch` test which should provide you with further usage details.